# store data from a file to a struct array

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have spent a lot of time the last two day and I stuck. I cant understand how pointers and structs work with a function.

I pass a array of type struct by reference and I parse a file to store the values. I used printf to see that it did word but back in main the values are wrong. I wonder if I have to use pointer to pointer to make it work.

here is the function

```
int parse_sightings(char *file, struct sightings_data *recs) {
    FILE *fptr;
    char buf[50];
    int lines=0;

    fptr = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        ferror(fptr);
        exit(1);
    } else {

        while (!feof(fptr)) {
            char ch = fgetc(fptr);
            if (ch == '\n') {
                lines++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",lines);
    rewind(fptr);
    recs = malloc(lines * sizeof (struct sightings_data));
    int index = 0;
    ///aber/dap/cetaceans/data/sightings_1.txt
    while (!feof(fptr)) {
        fscanf(fptr, "%s %c %lf %lf", &(recs + index)->id, &(recs + index)->type, &(recs + index)->lat, &(recs + index)->lon);
        index++;

    }
}
    fclose(fptr);
int x;

for (x = 0; x < lines; x++) {
    printf("%s %c %.2f %.2f\n", (recs + x)->id, (recs + x)->type, (recs + x)->lat, (recs + x)->lon);
}
return lines;
}
```

The printf gives the correct output. The problem appeals in the for in the main

In main:
I declare the struct here

```
struct sightings_data sight_recs[];
```

here is the function

```
lines_sights=parse_sightings(file_2,&sight_recs);
```

and finally a for to check the array

```
for(i=0;i<lines_sights;i++){
    printf("%s %c %.2f %.2f\n", (sight_recs + i)->id, (sight_recs + i)->type, (sight_recs + i)->lat, (sight_recs + i)->lon);
}
```

I couldnt find anything to help or any good example to example it clear. The most was basic and thinks have become confusing afterward. The debugger inform me that the lat, type, lon and id were out of range. But then how does the first for prints the data?

I would like to know what I am doing wrong, what is the best approach for this and any good resource to learn what more about structs in memory, how does it allocate it, how does it parse it etc.

Comment: 1) `ferror(fptr);`  BAD! And there is no meaning.

Comment: `struct sightings_data sight_recs[];` --> `struct sightings_data *sight_recs;` ,  `int parse_sightings(char *file, struct sightings_data *recs) {` --> `int parse_sightings(char *file, struct sightings_data **recs) {` ... `*recs = malloc(lines * sizeof (struct sightings_data));` ditto.

Comment: instead of ferror(), use perror() which prints the enclosed string, along with errno and the results of strerror() to stderr

Comment: ok that s work. But can you give me an brief explaination about my mistake. Was it so wrong? was it feasible?

Comment: the code exits when a fopen error occurs, so there is no need for the else clause.  suggest, for code clarity, that the '} else {' and trailing '}' be removed

Comment: ferror only checks to see if a file access has an error 1) the code passes it a null pointer, so there is no file access for it to test. ferror only returns a boolean to indicate if the last file access (must be passed a valid file pointer) had an error or not.  This tells the user nothing about what went wrong with the fopen.

Comment: feof() is only meaningful after a file access (I.E. not right after the file is opened)  suggest placing the fgetc() in the while statement

Comment: it is obvious that the file you copy/pasted from has tabs in it.  Tabs are always a bad idea, try using 4 spaces instead (most editors can be set to insert spaces when a tab key is pressed.

Comment: at the second call to feof(), that was already set by the prior fgetc(), and no access to the file has ocurred since then, so it will still be set. (rewind does not reset it) so the second while loop will never execute.  suggest placing the fscanf in the while statement

Comment: the fscanf format string parameter needs a leading ' ' to consume the leading white space, like the newline from the last line, otherwise it can/will fail.  Also, the returned value from fscanf needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful.  with 4 conversion operators in the format string, the check should be against 4

Comment: the returned value from malloc needs to be check for not NULL, to assure the operation was successful, before using the value

Comment: user3629249 I cant understand the issue about feof(). Rewind() returns the pointer to the beginning of the file. right? Why then feof cant indicate the end of file?

Answer (score 0):

> I cant understand the issue about feof(). Rewind() returns the pointer
>   to the beginning of the file. right? Why then feof cant indicate the
>   end of file?

`feof()` can indicate the end of file, but only after the end of the file has been encountered, that is, after it has been attempted to read past the end. So, your loop

```
    while (!feof(fptr)) {
        fscanf(fptr, "%s %c %lf %lf", &(recs + index)->id, &(recs + index)->type, &(recs + index)->lat, &(recs + index)->lon);
        index++;
        // Try printf("index = %d\n", index); here!
    }
```

will, after the last line's data has been read, not yet have bumped into the end-of-file, and will iterate the loop one more time. This might not be an issue here, but such usage of `feof()` can lead to errors if one isn't aware of the implications.